# Why can't I access the User's uid from the bloc's state in this example?

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication, bloc

After successfully signing in to Firestore using the flutterfire_ui pacakge, the user is taken to HomeScreen where initState adds a GetUser event, which eventually causes the UserBloc to yield a state object called UserLoaded with a property called activeUser, which should contain a User object with a uid property. However, when I try to access state.activeUser.uid from inside the Blockbuilder, it throws the following error:

The getter 'uid' isn't defined for the class 'Stream<User?>'.
lib/screens/home_page.dart:38

- 'Stream' is from 'dart:async'.
- 'User' is from 'package:firebase_practice/models/user.dart' ('lib/models/user.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'uid'.
  'HomeScreen state is: ${state.activeUser?.uid}',

Is this because I'm using both flutterfire_ui and FirebaseAuth? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

User Model

```
class User {
  final uid;
  final userName;
  final email;

  User({required  this.uid, this.userName, this.email});

}
```

AuthService:

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart' as auth;
import 'package:firebase_practice/models/user.dart';
    
class AuthService {

  final auth.FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth;

  AuthService({auth.FirebaseAuth? firebaseAuth}) 
  : _firebaseAuth = firebaseAuth ?? auth.FirebaseAuth.instance;

  //create a dart User from Firebase user
  User? _userFromFirebaseAuth(auth.User? user) {
  return User(uid: user!.uid, email: user!.email);
  }
 
  Stream<User?>? get user {
    return _firebaseAuth.authStateChanges().map(_userFromFirebaseAuth);
  }
```

UserBloc:

```
class UserBloc extends Bloc<UserEvent, UserState> {
  final AuthService  _authService;

  UserBloc( this._authService) : super(UserInitial()) {
    on<GetUser>(_getUser);
  }

  FutureOr<void> _getUser(GetUser event, Emitter<UserState> emit) async {
    Stream<User?>? user = await _authService.user;
    if(user != null){
      emit(UserLoaded(activeUser: user));
    }
  }
}
```

UserState:

```
class UserLoaded extends UserState {

   Stream<User?> activeUser;

  UserLoaded({required this.activeUser});

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [activeUser];
}
```

HomeScreen:

```
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<UserBloc, UserState>(
      builder: (context, state) {
        if (state is UserLoaded) {
          return Scaffold(
            body: Center(
              child: Text(
                'HomeScreen with state is: ${state.activeUser.uid}',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40),
              ),
            ),
          );
        }
        return CircularProgressIndicator();
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the 'uid' directly because 'activeUser' is a stream of 'user'. So you could wrap your Text-widget with a StreamBuilder and provide 'state.activeUser' as the stream:

```
StreamBuilder(
  stream: state.activeUser,
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      return Text(snapshot.data?.uid : "");
    }
    return Text("");
  },
);
```

But I have a question there, why do you save the stream itself inside your UserState? Why not save only the User and emit a new state whenever authStateChanges fires? You could do something like this:

```
class UserBloc extends Bloc<UserEvent, UserState> {
  final AuthService  _authService;
  StreamSubscription<User?> _userSubscription;

  UserBloc(this._authService) : super(UserInitial()) {
    on<GetUser>(_getUser);
  }

  void _getUser(GetUser event, Emitter<UserState> emit) {
    _userSubscription ??= _authService.user.listen((user) {
      emit(UserLoaded(activeUser: user));
    });
  }
}
```

So you can change the UserState to hold a User? instead of a stream and you can access it directly inside you widget how you did it in your sample.

**Attention: The code samples are only from my memory and probably wont work out of the box.**